# increasing x y values in matpplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have made a plot in Jupyter and I got output as shown in picture but I want to increase my x values like it has 1995,2000,2005,2010,2015 on x axis and I want more x values like say 1995,1997,1999,2001,2003...so on.

I have enter this code but I am unable to produce more x values and y values as mentioned before.

```
 fig=plt.figure(figsize=(9, 7), dpi= 100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')    
 plt.plot(df_3)
```

[image: click here for the graph]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xticks` such as

```
plt.xticks(min_x, max_x+1, 1.0)
```

You can also set your interval 2 or 3 to have more number on your x-axis.

Comment: well after searching i found this and it works too "" plt.xticks(np.arange(1990,2020,step=2))""